# Importing styling for material web component textfield gives error

Tags: sass

I am trying to implement material textfield web component. I have opened up a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-meadow-74et5?file=/src/styles.scss) here to experiment with it. I have followed their [documentation](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field/#outlined-text), and I have installed the textfield, used the material styling in sass like this:

```
@use "@material/textfield";
@include textfield.core-styles;
```

But, I get:

> Error: Invalid CSS after "@include textfield": expected 1 selector or
>   at-rule, was ".core-styles;"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code in question does work, only not in the codesandbox but when compiled locally using dart-sass, it runs correctly. My suspicion is that Codesandbox uses a version of SASS that doesn't support modules because it is raising a warning in code about unknown `@use` rule.

If your current intention is to experiment only, the easiest way is to link pre-packaged CSS by dropping:

```
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
```

to head as described [here](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/) and removing imports from your SCSS file (you can even use pre-packaged JS). For real-life development, you will probably setup Webpack anyway.

You can check a working sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-sara-lgfet

Comment: Do you have any advice/resources for importing these in a webpack environment?

Comment: @rprez Use a pre-configured environment like create-react-app, next or anything similar for your language if you can.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, fixed it by removing "node-sass" and installing "[sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)"

Thanks to this guy:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/5502#issuecomment-586061492

Answer (score 1):

I suppose Google meant some additional settings in webpack, for the actual problem is that every path in their instructions is a path to a folder, not a certain file. Most likely these folders should be interpreted by webpack as some subpackages as they all contain `_index.scss` files. I think there's something wrong with dispatching rules (including problems with @forward instruction).
I didn't find completely automatic deсision for below reason:

- Required mixins are sometimes declared in the `foldername/_index.scss` file and sometimes in `foldername/_foldername.scss` file. And though `foldername/_foldername.scss` file is always added to the `foldername/_index.scss` file through the `@forward` instruction, it doesnt always work fine.
  So for making my vue.js adapters I just check which file contains required mixins, then correcth the path and add alias  - like this:

```css
@use "@material/button/button" as button; // here button/button worked fine
@use "@material/checkbox/checkbox" as checkbox;
@use "@material/icon-button/_index.scss" as icon-button; // here had to use checkbox/_index.scss
@use "@material/data-table/data-table";

@include checkbox.core-styles;
@include icon-button.core-styles;
@include data-table.core-styles;
@include data-table.theme-baseline;
@include button.core-styles;
```